Positive and simple roots of the Lie algebra $B_2$
For the past few days I've been studying a course called "groups & symmetries". Currently I'm busy with a chapter called "the Cartan-Weyl basis". I have a question concerning the Lie algebra $B_2$, which is $so(5)$. I wanted to determine all positive roots of this Lie algbera. In total I have found six, namely
$$(2,0) \quad (0,2) \quad (1,-1) \quad (1,1) \quad (-1,0) \quad (0,-1)$$
However I do not think that this is right since I can't find the simple roots of this Lie algebra. To determine the positive roots I used the raising operators given on the following picture

where i and j are either 1 or 2. So i found a total of 6 elements of $B_+$ and thus 6 positive roots. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Can you give some more details here? How are your raising operators defined? You give a set $\mathcal B_+$. Is this a set of vectors in some vector space? You say that $i$ and $j$ are either $1$ or $2$, but is $n$ any integer? How do your pairs (e.g. (2,0)) relate to the set $\mathcal B_+$?

Please do not rely on pictures of text.

@krm2233 I think those are supposed to be root vectors in a basis such that the Cartan is diagonal and $n$ is the rank of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2n+1)$ so $n=2$ here. It doesn't add up correctly though and the use of $\mathcal{E}$ to mean (I think) matrices with $1$ non-zero element is perhaps a little confusing when the roots are often written $\pm\varepsilon_i \pm \varepsilon_j$

$(-1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ can't both represent roots let alone positive roots since in a reduced root system the only multiple of a root $\alpha$ that is also a root is $-\alpha$.
The usual way to represent the $B_2$ roots system with integer vectors would give the roots as $(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,-1) , (-1,0),(0,-1),(-1,-1),(-1,1)$. I've written these so the first four form a nice choice of positive roots and the last 4 are their negatives. The simple roots would then be $(1,-1)$ and $(0,1)$.
I'm not sure I follow your definition of $B_+$ as that seems to have too many roots to me. $B_2$ has $8$ roots total and $4$ positive roots (in general $B_n$ has $n^2$ positive roots). I suspect that initial $\leq$ should just be a $<$.
Edit: thinking on this a bit longer I am more sure that the problem is simply that the $\leq$ should be a $<$. A common notation for the roots in $B_n$ is $\{\pm\varepsilon_i \pm\varepsilon_j | 1\leq i<j\leq n\} \cup \{\pm\varepsilon_i|1\leq i\leq n\}$ One choice of positive roots is then:
$\{\varepsilon_i \pm \varepsilon_j | 1\leq i<j\leq n\} \cup \{\varepsilon_i|1\leq i\leq n\}$ with simple roots $\{\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2, \dots, \varepsilon_{n-1} - \varepsilon_n,\varepsilon_n\}$. Note the similarity to your $B_+$ although these are roots not the root vectors and we do not allow $i = j$ ever.
In the case of $B_2$ our choice of positive roots in this notation are $\{\varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2, \varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2, \varepsilon_1 , \varepsilon_2\}$ and the simple roots are $\{\varepsilon_1 - \varepsilon_2, \varepsilon_2\}$ (note in the basis of the $\varepsilon_i$ this is just the $(1,-1)$ and $(0,1)$ that I mentioned earlier).
